# Creating EJB remote references into a client witout EAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

Well, this is my development environment:

- I am using Java 1.8 and Eclipse 4.5.1 (Mars), J2EE tools and plugins installed to work with WildFly 8 as Application Server
- I created a Java EJB project, with a simple HelloWorld stateless session bean class. It implements 2 interfaces: @Remote and/or @Local, where I defined a String getHelloWorld() stub.
- Now, I have my client for consuming the EJB: A Dynamic Web Project with one Servlet.
  Inside the servlet, I can inject the ejb class using annotations, like this:

@EJB
private HelloWorldLocal bean;
or
@EJB
private HelloWorldRemote bean;

As you see, I declared the bean as HelloWorldLocal/HelloWorldRemote types. However, if I want to deploy and run my application, 
I need to put the EJB and Web projects into an EAR first. That allows the Servlet to know and compile the HelloWorldLocal or HelloWorldRemote bean types, by simply adding the EJB project on 
the Build Path as Project, or even by putting the EJB project as a Deployment Assembly directive.

I'd like to create a client outside the EAR (a remote Swing application or Remote WebSite). That means my client will
have not the chance to adding the EJB project interfaces as project references in the build path as I did with the EAR. Even if I want to call
the remote bean with JNDI, I need to cast the lookup() object to those types in order to use the bean methods.

The question is:

How can I get the HelloWorldRemote/HelloWorldLocal bean types from my remote client without EARs, if those interfaces are declared into an separate EJB Project?
(Of course, I dont want to create a .jar with the EJB project here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to share the only one solution that I found: I have to create a .jar file, with all the EJB interfaces (@Remote, @Local, and so on), and use it like referenced types on my remote clients.

This .jar would be outside any EAR. however, it needs jboss-client.jar because of the @ annotations. So, I packaged all, interfaces and jboss-client.jar, exported them to a .jar and I added this new file in my EJB and clients projects as external jar! Now I am able to use the HelloWorld* types on EJB classes implementations and @EJB client variables.

If I want a remote Web client, I've placed the EJB project with a Web Project module, into a EAR - Definitely we need an EAR. The Web module has Servlets, and the servlets handles the @EJB variables and responses. So, Outside this EAR, I just need to use URL's to the servlets and, you got it: EJB method results are reached from remote web clients.

In desktop applications with JNDI, I just put the interfaces .jar like external jar into the client project. In that way, I can cast the .lookup() to HelloWorld* types and using its methods.

- I hope it helps.

Comment: here is, pretty much, as I did:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

Answer (score 2):

And what about portable JNDI lookup? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html It should work if the EJB in the same JVM as your client.

Comment: The point is: supose we have a client calling:
Object bean = context.lookup(jndipath);
And next, I need a bean method:
((RemoteEjbType) bean).beanMethod();
The RemoteEjbType is unknown from the client side, since that type is not defined in the client project, but the ejb project instead.

Comment: If you want to call remote interfaces you have to register it locally.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly that I want... but I don't know how to achieve it. Can you give me more details about the register process, please?

Comment: Some resources.
JBoss:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI
Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15505/access.htm#i1020000

Comment: I created a new Client Application Project (although I wanted a desktop application) from Eclipse, with the application-client.xml with the ejb-ref tag, but still the remote/local interfases are not recognized when declaring bean variable types.

Comment: Out of the Web app you can just access remote interfaces. Maybe the end of this article can help: https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/entry/accessing_ejb_3_session_beans (added libraries)

Comment: The article explains we need a "dependence on EJB module" to access the HomeRemote interface. So I think that using a .jar containing those interfaces as I did, it is not a bad solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking, and I haven't done this in years, but the normal approach for this would to to create an **EJB client JAR** containing only the client's bean dependencies and remote interfaces. To best accomplish this, you'll want to use a tool such as Maven to build your project which contains an [EJB plugin for this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html). If you're not using Maven, you're going to be limited by the tooling within Eclipse, though at one point it did contain [EJB client generation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ejb.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftecrtpro.html) support.  The [Wildfly documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI?_sscc=t) on EJB client setup might help also, but explicitly mentions that packaging the client is out of scope.

Comment: Perhaps I tried to be too much detailed and my question became confused. Anyway, I think you got the point. I'll read and test your info, and I'll come back with more feedback. That's really valuable answer. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the EJB client generation on eclipse, and it works. 
(It just had to add a jboss-client.jar on the client project that eclipse made).
However, I realized this approach is putting the generated EJB client project as an EAR Library
inside the EJB HelloWorld project, so It makes me think I was using the inverse dependency
between project references. I am not sure if that allows me to keep the client & ejb projects independency or
it just moves the problem from the client to the server side.

Comment: Anyway, still I am not sure about how can I do 
if I need to create a remote web client outside the ejb project EAR. I begin to suspect the EARs are totally essentials 
in eclipse for these cases.